# MVC evolution and improvements

Tags: model-view-controller, frameworks

I just found the [MVC was initially proposed in 88](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=50759) [[here is the pdf file](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~redmiles/ics227-SQ04/papers/KrasnerPope88.pdf)] but unfortunately ASP.NET just recently implement it.

Do you know which is the most used MVC design pattern in the our days frameworks? I'm curious to know how MVC has evolved during the times and which is the best approach(what make it a good approach)? For example: a) in some versions, views doesn't interact with models. b) model has to be bigger than controller. On short, which are the gold rules for a good MVC implementation even if a certain framework doesn't require it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as MVC design patterns it's been in use for more than 20 years in a wide variety of various languages and frameworks.

It's either being used in or is the basis of the design patterns being used in a wide variety of applications.

The core of MVC has to do with separating your code so that things have a logical progression through your code and gives you a simple way to separate your code.  I'm not sure I understand your question about wanting to know which is the most used MVC design pattern since it is the design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#History), it was first described in 1979, not '88.  The paper you link to even has a reference at the end titled "Model View Controller" from 1987, which is a good hint that 1988 was not the first proposal.  :-)

I don't think it's "unfortunate" so much as "inevitable" that big companies didn't get around to implementing it for decades.  Big companies tend to move slowly.

Sorry, was there a question here?